# How to show the data returned via hook_views_data() in a page?

Tags: 6, views

I have hook_views_api as follows :

```
function hook_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 2,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'faq') . '/views',
  );
}
```

and i have the hook_views_data() function in views folder as follows :

```
function hook_views_data() {
  // faq_questions table.
  $data['faq_questions']['table']['group'] = t('FAQ');
  $data['faq_questions']['table']['join'] = array(
    'node' => array(
      'left_field' => 'nid',
      'field' => 'nid',
    ),
  );
  $data['faq_questions']['question'] = array(
    'title' => t('FAQ short question'),
    'help' => t('The short question text for FAQ nodes.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
  );
  $data['faq_questions']['detailed_question'] = array(
    'title' => t('FAQ detailed question'),
    'help' => t('The long question text for FAQ nodes.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
  );


  return $data;
}
```

How can i show the results returned by the hook_views_data() `in a page` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to print the output to the page using [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Just add `print_r($data)` at the end of the function, before your return statement.

If you're just printing this data out so you can take a look at it for debugging purposes than you might want to use [error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) instead. For `error_log` just add `error_log(print_r($data, 1))` at the end of your function, before the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use handlers to theme output of data. Views is all about firing queries. As you have defined base table in hook_view_data(), it's easy to query the table and render results to template.

For other approaches and good understanding of API, follow these[(1)](http://evolvingweb.ca/story/developing-views-part-i-describing-your-data-views)[(2)](http://www.grasmash.com/article/demystifying-views-api-developers-guide-integrating-views) tutorials:

Comment: i know the hook_theme system , but whats the role of views and making the data from there ?